# Can there be a way to exploit PHP include_once() when the input is filtered?

Tags: php, lfi

Let's assume there is this code for including other php files from user input (yes, I know it's a bad choice):

```
$input = addslashes($_GET["input"]);

if (strpos($input, '../') === false) {
    include_once('/path/to/php/files/'.$input);
} else { echo('Invalid parameter!'); }
```

This code adds slashes to single and double quotes, and then check for `../` in the string, and if it does not find it, includes the file.

Assuming that the hacker has written some code to include to other folder, and the hacker needs to access that file with `?input=../../folder/extcode`, can there be a vulnerabillity here?

Comment: Maybe LFI is still possible using base64, or url-encoding...

Comment: @MoonsikPark Are you sure that `include_once("..\\..\\folder\\extcode")` (what you get after `addslashes`) doesn't actually work on Windows? The Windows command line is kind enough to just collapse \\ into \, would not surprise me if PHP does the same. Unfortunately, I don't have a PHP installation on Windows to test this on.

Comment: @Anders Neither do I. Think it will work though.

Answer (score 5):

This code is vulnerable to LFI when running on Windows systems, because those systems will accept a path containing a directory traversal which uses backslashes (like `\..\..\`).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to block is a LFI, but I think you are still vulnerable. This kind of scenarios are usually potentially vulnerable to LFI and RFI.

It seems your code is not vulnerable to RFI because of the local path prefix. (Link to both LFI and RFI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability).

Just for clarification, on RFI the attacker will try to include a remote file using a payload like `http://evilsite/evil.php` and as you can see it doesn't contain '../' on it. To be protected of this, you should configure on your php.ini the `allow_url_include` and be sure that it is off. Otherwise you could be be hacked using RFI depending of the input. So it's a good practice to set this off if not needed.

Talking about LFI I think your code is not safe. Ok you are blocking strings like '../' but maybe the attacker could encode it someway to bypass your protection. As @game0ver said in a comment, the attacker could use base64 or url-encoding and maybe more. Be careful!

So, summarizing. You are **NOT** vulnerable to **RFI** but, **YES** you are probably vulnerable to **LFI**.

Comment: How would an RFI work on OPs sample code? There's a local path prefix.

Comment: Oops, maybe you are right... I'll edit my answer just to talk about the risks of RFI... but I still think it could be vulnerable to LFI. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis as you said, I think it's still exploitable through url/base64 encoding... I think it's worth testing. Also an RFI is unlikely to happen, **but** it's possible an attacker to use PHP wrapper functions and achieve RCE, rare but happens.

Comment: Yeah, that's completely true!

Comment: How would this be exploitable with base64 or URL encoding? For that to happend, there would need to be something in the include function that decodes, but to my knowledge there isn't.

Comment: That’s not my code and if it’s vulnerable I need to have a solid proof that it’s vulnerable. Can you provide a snippet or some kind of guidence to exploit it?

Comment: @Anders as mentioned [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) (in the notes section) superglobals are already url-decoded, so url-encoding is indeed a possible attacking vector.

Comment: @game0ver No, because `strpos` also recieves the URL-decoded version. What's important here is that `strpos` and `include` see the same string. If it is vulnerable, what would an exploit look like?

Comment: Not saying it is safe though, I don't know that.

Comment: @Anders good point! You're right, I missed that! I don't know though if it's possible to use other php functions to perform RCE, without having the app to test, I can only guess.

Comment: `strpos` recieves a url-decoded string, so encoded strings like `..%27` won't work. Also, things like `php://filter/<stuff>` or `data://text/plain;base64,<stuff>` or null byte injection won't work because of the prefix. Backticks won't work because it's `addslashes()`d and so on. I can't see any vulnerability on my reach. Maybe if the user can reverse the string through the input that could be a problem though.

Answer (score 2):

#### RFI and LFI

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be directly exploitable.  As discussed elsewhere in comments, RFI is not possible because of the prefix, and LFI is not possible in linux because (I believe) there isn't any way to escape the `strpos` via encoding.  PHP would automatically decode any URL encoded strings before placing it into the `$_GET` super variable, and any encoding that didn't trigger the `strpos` search also wouldn't register as a forward slash for the purposes of the include call (at least, I couldn't find any successful attack vectors). Keep duskwuff's answer in mind though - LFI is possible here on windows.

#### Alternate attacks

However, that doesn't mean that it can't help.  In particular, open includes like this are the sort of vulnerability that let's you make a smaller vulnerability much bigger.  The immediate thought that comes to mind is to check if this website has an image upload function anywhere.  If so, and you know where the images are saved, you can try embedding valid PHP in the EXIF data of a jpg image which you then upload to the server.  Normally such code is not exploitable, because you don't have anyway to run your PHP on the server.  But, with an open include like this, you can upload your file and then use this weakness to run it (since the uploaded file will most likely exist inside `/path/to/php/files` the lack of a fully qualified LFI vulnerability won't matter).  From there you can do whatever you want.

Using user-input to build an include path is almost *always* a bad idea, and is rarely necessary.  Even if there isn't an immediate weakness, that doesn't mean it can't help you when exploiting other ones.

#### Better security

I think it's worth taking a minute to explain how something like this *should* be secured.  It's hard to give an exact solution without more context, but usually something like this can be broken down into a more secure two-step process:

1. Use `realpath` to let the system resolve all directory-traversal attempts and get a final absolute path
2. Make sure that the final absolute path lives in a safe directory for you to include files from, or explicitly white-list against a list of safe includes

You never want to let the user include an arbitrary file.  Figure out exactly what file is going to be included as a result of their user input, and filter that through a whitelist.  That is the only way to do this securely.